# ember build - Get error "controllers/application-compiled.js: line 1, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict"."

Tags: ember.js

Novice in Ember JS. Using:

```
➜  rarwe git:(master) ✗ ember -v
version: 0.2.7
node: 0.12.4
npm: 2.11.0
```

I'm trying to run ember build, but I get the errors:

```
➜  rarwe git:(master) ✗ ember build
version: 0.2.7
Building.
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 1, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict".
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 3, col 23, 'exports' is not defined.
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 9, col 14, 'require' is not defined.
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 44, col 1, 'exports' is not defined.
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 46, col 1, 'module' is not defined.
controllers/application-compiled.js: line 46, col 18, 'exports' is not defined.

6 errors

===== 1 JSHint Error

Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".
```

Any help will be appreciated.

---

Hi, Blong... Thank you for your attention... Here is the content of the file controllers/application-compiled.js:

```
var checker   = require('ember-cli-version-checker');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ember-cli-babel',

  shouldSetupRegistryInIncluded: function() {
    return !checker.isAbove(this, '0.2.0');
  },

  setupPreprocessorRegistry: function(type, registry) {
    var addon = this;

    registry.add('js', {
      name: 'ember-cli-babel',
      ext: 'js',
      toTree: function(tree) {
        return require('broccoli-babel-transpiler')(tree, getOptions(addon));
      }
    });
  },

  included: function(app) {
    this._super.included.apply(this, arguments);
    this.app = app;

    if (this.shouldSetupRegistryInIncluded()) {
      this.setupPreprocessorRegistry('parent', app.registry);
    }
  }
};

function getOptions(addonContext) {
  var baseOptions = (addonContext.parent && addonContext.parent.options) || (addonContext.app && addonContext.app.options),
      options = baseOptions && baseOptions['babel'] || {};
  // Ensure modules aren't compiled unless explicitly set to compile
  options.blacklist = options.blacklist || ['es6.modules'];

  // do not enable non-standard transforms
  if (!('nonStandard' in options)) {
    options.nonStandard = false;
  }

  if (options.compileModules === true) {
    if (options.blacklist.indexOf('es6.modules') >= 0) {
      options.blacklist.splice(options.blacklist.indexOf('es6.modules'), 1);
    }

    delete options.compileModules;
  } else {
    if (options.blacklist.indexOf('es6.modules') < 0) {
      options.blacklist.push('es6.modules');
    }
  }

  // Ember-CLI inserts its own 'use strict' directive
  options.blacklist.push('useStrict');
  options.highlightCode = false;

  return options;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context into how you set up your ember project?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick answer. Sorry for my poor English - I understand 'context' like the following:
   Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)
   I installed node via Homebrew

Comment: Do I need to install AMD or something like tihs?

Comment: Have you followed the [tutorial](http://www.ember-cli.com/)?  Trying to see if you ran "ember init" or "ember new" before trying to build (you have to).

Comment: Yes, I ran "ember new rarwe". I'm following a tutorial from the book "Rock and Roll with Ember.js"(by the way, an excellent book for beginners).

Comment: Did u fix this issue? are u able to run the project?

Comment: No, I didn't yet, Blessenm. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you post the content of  the file `controllers/application-compiled.js`?

Comment: You might take a look at this, it may be helpful: https://github.com/balinterdi/rock-and-roll-api

Comment: Hi Blong... Thanks for your attention... I edited the question and put the content of the file there.